# Unable to deinit in swift using firestore database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the below code for deinit function using firestore database in swift ios, but it is giving me error, I need to use deinit when the table view controller is loaded, please assist, thank you

Error

```
Cannot invoke 'removeObserver' with an argument list of type '(CollectionReference?)'
```

Code

```
fileprivate var _refHandle: CollectionReference!


   deinit {
        if let refHandle = _refHandle {
            self.ref.removeObserver(_refHandle)
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [addSnapshotListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#/c:objc(cs)FIRQuery(im)addSnapshotListener:) to attach a listener to a CollectionReference (which is also a Query), note its documented return type.  It returns a [ListenerRegistration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Protocols/ListenerRegistration.html) object, and you call its `remove()` method to stop listening.

Please [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) for more details and examples.

Comment: thanks can you help with some coding, as I am newbie to cloud firestore

Comment: There are code sample in the documentation I linked to.